# SetContentView() Error: Android.Views.InflateException

Tags: android, xml, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Whenever I go to my new activity, an error occurs at `SetContentView()` method inside its `OnCreate()` method.

The error states: `Unhandled Exception: Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown> occurred`.

I looked up towards other similar questions and their answers, however their solution does not work for me.

My XML code for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:id="@+id/testing"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <Toolbar
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/playMusicBackBtn" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Song Title"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/nowPlayingSongTitle" />
            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/space1" />
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/settings_icon"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/playMusicSetting" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </Toolbar>
<!--Song Image-->
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/songImage"
        android:layout_margin="25dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
        <TextView
            android:text="Song Title - Song Artist"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/songTitleDisplay" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/space1" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/favorite_off"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/addFavoriteBtn"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
<!--Interactive Buttons that deal with the Media player-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:weightSum="4">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/shuffle_off"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/shuffleBtn" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/space1" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/play_prev"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/playPrevBtn" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/space1" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/play"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/playPauseBtn" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/space1" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/play_next"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/playNextBtn" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/space1" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/repeat_off"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/repeatBtn" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/musicSeekerBar" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Current - Max"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/musicDuration" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem occurred mainly after I added the seekerbar and the textview (At the bottom of the XML).

Logcat (Few lines before the event happened):

```
    09-13 09:09:28.332 I/art     ( 4650): Clamp target GC heap from 283MB to 256MB
09-13 09:09:28.332 I/art     ( 4650): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 251MB/256MB, paused 597us total 35.921ms
09-13 09:09:28.332 I/art     ( 4650): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 13MB allocation
09-13 09:09:28.332 I/art     ( 4650): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-13 09:09:28.365 I/art     ( 4650): Clamp target GC heap from 283MB to 256MB
09-13 09:09:28.365 I/art     ( 4650): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 251MB/256MB, paused 500us total 32.744ms
09-13 09:09:28.365 W/art     ( 4650): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 14107548 byte allocation with 4666448 free bytes and 4MB until OOM"
09-13 09:09:28.366 D/skia    ( 4650): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Also, I am using Visual Studio 2017 as my IDE.

Comment: Share your log cat

Comment: Add the complete logcat

Comment: your imageview source file has too large MB.

Comment: Its something related to the images which your daemon is unable to scale and convert and system memory leaks occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its something related to the images which your daemon is unable to scale and convert and system memory leaks occur.

Try reducing the size of all your drawables and image sources. This will solve the out of memort issue.

Comment: Hope that helped:)

Comment: That helped a lot, I also had a few Bitmap objects lying around that took up a large sum of space too, which I removed.

Comment: Good to know :)